# What are the disadvantages of eager loading?

Tags: optimization, eager-loading, craftcms

I've been given the task of eager loading global components and templates on Craft CMS.
Can someone please explain like I'm 5 why eager loading isn't implemented on all templates and why you wouldn't eager load everything?
I don't really understand eager loading - isn't it better performance wise to eager load everything?

Answer (score 0):

Better for the user (possibly) as results are returned quicker but worse for your hosting as it's working harder. Not a problem if you have plenty of RAM/CPU to throw at it, but maybe not so good on shared environments.